# Need to disable "hover" effects in Nimbus LAF in Java

Tags: java, nimbus

The reason I need this: the jTabbedPane in Nimbus LAF seems to redraw the whole page, and I cannot have it. I tried everything.

The nly scenario the redraw doesn't happen is when I do not use Nimbus LAF.

I have tried basic properties.
I have tried changing background painters of jTabbedPane and make them essentially draw nothing

None does it. The jTabbed Pane still runs some hover events that messes other things.

**WHAT I NEED**

What I need is to entirely disable hover events that the Nimbus LAF has perhaps generated.

How can I make jTabbedPane trigger no event at all when mouse hovers on its tabs, in Nimbus LAF? Again without using Nimbus, all is good.

Comment: Provide code so that we can help you.

Comment: Not a code thing. How to disable "hover" listeners auto-generated by Nimbus LAF. I do not want them handled.

Comment: Does your tab content have any components which do custom painting?  I am wondering if the repainting was not due to hovering over a tab, but due to moving over the custom painted component.  It is normal for mouse movements to trigger partial painting of a component.

Comment: There are drawimage all over the place, which are all double buffered. Images don't disappear but do a quick flash. 


I think the hover listener, in fact, **slows down the listener on com port**.


Nevertheless, the whole mouse hover trigger the tabbed pane causes because of Nimbus is useless anyway, and slows down other stuff. 

I understand that there might be other solutions, but I really prefer to cut off whatever it is that Nimbus is doing that listens on mouse hover. Not just removing the background painter, but disabling the listeners.